# Mongoose not returning full document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Im using mongolab as my db host. 
I created locations schema and insure index '2dsphere'
Document example:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "54d6347ce4b04aad9bbdc8ac"
    },
    "name": "Vacation",
    "address": {
        "city": "Ashkelon",
        "street": "Afridat"
    },
    "location": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
            34.552955,
            31.671384
        ]
    }
}
```

When using Mongoose to query the collection everything works great, but I can't retrieve the location field. 
When using mongo shell I get the full document(with the location).

```
// the query Im using:
 Mongoose: locations.find({ _id: ObjectId("54d63538e4b04aad9bbdc8b4") }) { fields: undefined }
```

This query only return the following feilds: name, address and _id.

**Update:**

Schema:

```
var locationSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    address: {city: String, street: String},
    location: {
        type: [Number],  // [<longitude>, <latitude>]
        index: '2dsphere'      // create the geospatial index
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you post your schema definition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `location` field in your schema needs to match the structure in your doc. Your current schema defines it as a legacy coordinate pair, but your doc is using a GeoJSON `Point`, so change your schema to look like this instead:

```
var locationSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    address: {city: String, street: String},
    location: {
        type: { type: String },
        coordinates: [Number]
    }
});    
locationSchema.index({location: '2dsphere'});
```

Note that you need to define the index for `location` separately because it contains its own fields in the schema.

Comment: Thanks you sir.
Back to read more about the legacy coordinates and the new GeoJSON.